# Are there alternatives to multiple buffering?

Tags: opengl, double-buffering

I'm learning about game programming. So far, my sources lead me to believe that [multiple buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) is the best technique for redrawing in OpenGL.

Are there other redrawing techniques? What are their advantages/disadvantages?

I'm not sure about terminology yet, but googling as best as I can hasn't yielded much result yet. Does anyone have any experience with redrawing techniques besides multiple buffering?

Comment: Are you asking if there are alternatives that have the same benefits? If you're fine with the graphical glitches you can simply not use a buffer.

Comment: This almost feels like "I know how to do math with my numbers. But I want to mess with my numbers without math. What other techniques are there?"

Comment: @Almo: I'm not trying to trick anybody. I'm not trying to fish for anything. I'm not trying to turn SO into a "mechanical turk". I was just wondering if there existed more than one design pattern for redrawing. If there aren't, please say so in an answer so i can accept it and leave you guys alone.

Comment: I know you're not trying to trick us, my comment was only to explain what it looks like to me. Sort of like "I want to roll things, but I don't want to use ball bearings or wheels or anything circular". Double buffering is just what you do.

Comment: @Almo: When you get accused of that so often, you tend to have your guard up when asking on SE. Please accept my apology.

Comment: Hey, it's not a problem. :)

Comment: The only alternative to having buffers is to... not have buffers. (As anticlimactic as that is...) As for *why* have buffers, Trevor explained that really well for [this question on what problem multiple buffering solves](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82318/what-problem-does-double-or-triple-buffering-solve-in-modern-games). I think reading that might answer the question that underlies this one in your head. Does it?

Comment: However, there are some problems caused by buffering (such as input lag) and on higher refresh rates double buffering is less of a necessity. An alternative to double buffering could be that the GPU writes to lines of the buffer that have already been processed this frame. That would require some sort of sync between GPU and monitor. Things which AMD and NVIDIA area working on. So if there are alternatives is a valid question, unfortunately the answer is that there are no real alternatives at this time.